# After navigating to a specific screen in the stack, the screen stays, stack doesn't reset and back button disappears

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I am building a mobile app in react native. In the App, I have a side menu which appears when we click on the burger button. I have a search screen, when i make search and the list appears, I click on an item of the list and i navigate to a screen named NewsDetailsScreen which show the news in details, this NewsDetailsScreen is inside a stack navigator named NewsNavigator which i has a top screen named NewsListScreen. The first issue is that the back arrow does not appear in the header of the details screen and second problem is if i navigate to a different screen and i come to Latest News in the side bar menu, the details screen stays there but what i want is to see NewsListScreen. I tried different solutions from google but none worked so it made me frustrated ! please help me solve this.

Thank you in advance

this is the main navigator, the RootNavigator is the side menu drawer:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import CustomDrawer from './../components/CustomDrawer';
import AboutScreen from './../screens/AboutScreen';
import NewsNavigator from './NewsNavigator';
import YoutubeChannelsListScreen from './../screens/YoutubeChannelsListScreen';
import DocumentariesListScreen from './../screens/DocumentariesListScreen';
import LeaderboardsNavigator from './../navigation/LeaderboardsNavigator';
import YoutubeNavigator from './YoutubeNavigator';
import SearchScreen from './../screens/SearchScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './../screens/SettingsScreen';
import RootNavigator from './RootNavigator';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import colors from '../config/colors';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = ({ theme, darkModeOn }) => {
    //const [darkModeOn, setDarkModeOn] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: theme.headerColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: theme.color,
            }}
            detachInactiveScreens={false}
        >
            {/* <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={RootNavigator} theme={theme} /> */}
            <Stack.Screen name="Root">
                {(props) => (
                    <RootNavigator
                        {...props}
                        theme={theme}
                        darkModeOn={darkModeOn}
                    />
                )}
            </Stack.Screen>
            <Stack.Screen name="Latest News" component={NewsNavigator} />
            <Stack.Screen name="F1 On Youtube" component={YoutubeNavigator} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

this is NewsNavigator.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import NewsListScreen from './../screens/NewsListScreen';
import NewsDetailsScreen from './../screens/NewsDetailsScreen';
import SearchScreen from '../screens/SearchScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const NewsNavigator = () => (
    <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            headerShown: false,
        }}
        initialRouteName="NewsListScreen"
    >
        <Stack.Screen name="NewsListScreen" component={NewsListScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SearchScreen" component={SearchScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="NewsDetailsScreen"
            component={NewsDetailsScreen}
            options={{ headerShown: true, title: '' }}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
);

export default NewsNavigator;
```

and this is the section where i am accessing NewsDetailsScreen:

```
<Card
                                title={item.title}
                                feedName={item.feedName}
                                date={item.pubDate}
                                imageUrl={item.image}
                                darkModeOn={darkModeOn}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    if (selected.value == 'news') {
                                        navigation.navigate('Latest News', {
                                            screen: 'NewsDetailsScreen',
                                            params: item,
                                        });
                                    } else if (selected.value == 'videos') {
                                        navigation.navigate(
                                            'F1 On Youtube',
                                            {
                                                screen: 'YoutubeVideoDetailsScreen',
                                                params: item,
                                            }
                                        );
                                    } else if (
                                        selected.value == 'documentaries'
                                    ) {
                                        openBrowserAsync(item.link);
                                    } else if (
                                        selected.value == 'channels'
                                    ) {
                                        openBrowserAsync(item.link);
                                    }
                                }}
                            />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it, I have to add a TouchableOpacity to the top of the NewsDetailsScreen and turn off the header for that screen

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate('NewsListScreen');
    }}
   style={{ width: '100%', height: 45, flexDirection: 'row' }}
                activeOpacity={1}
            >
                <Text style={styles.backText}>&#x2039;</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```